# How to add a time limit to a JS Promise resolve (reject Promise on timeout)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Currently trying to teach myself how Promises work in JavaScript.

So I want to create a Promise in which I do a complex calculation. If that calculation completes successfully in time I want the Promise to resolve, but if the calculation takes too long the Promise should reject with a timeout error. The available time is predefined, e.g. 1000ms.

My sample code looks like this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const result = complexCalculation();
  return resolve(result);  //this should be called when complexCalculation completed in under 1000ms
  return reject('timeout error');  //and this if 1000ms have passed without getting a result
})
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I tried different things already like an async function and setTimeout, but none of it worked the way I tried to implement it. I'm still very new to JS in general so please bear with me.

Comment: It the `complexCalculation` is synchronous, there's nothing you can do. (And you should not be using promises)

Comment: Well, all I have to do to make it asynchronous is to add `async` to the function definition and add `await` to the calculation inside, right?

Comment: No. If the calculations are synchronous, then adding `await` will do nothing. You can only `await` promises. What you *can* do is split up the complex calculation into multiple chunks and put artificial small delays between them, and also at each of those points check the current time for a deadline and abort the calculation if you hit the timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to set up a promise with a timeout reject:

```js
function calcWithTimeout(timeout) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  
    // start timeout
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(
      () => reject('longCalculation took too long'),
      timeout
    );
    
    // start calculation
    longCalculation().then(result => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
  
}

// a fake calculation that takes 1 second
function longCalculation() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('your calculation completed');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const pre = document.getElementById('result');

const myFn = (timeout) => {
  pre.innerHTML = 'calling calcWithTimeout with timeout = ' +
    timeout + '\n';
  
  calcWithTimeout(timeout)
  .then(result => {
    pre.innerHTML += 'result: ' + result;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    pre.innerHTML += 'error: ' + err;
  });
}
```

```css
#result {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFn(2000)">Long Timeout</button>
<button onclick="myFn(500)">Short Timeout</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your detailed answer!
So if I understand correctly, I have to return the result of the longCalculation as a new Promise resolve?

Comment: @DaDo I wrong `longCalculation` with a Promise/resolve to mimic a long-running function. But if any function is going to take a long time, it's a good idea to have it return a Promise that resolves on completion. That will ensure it won't block.

Comment: So I implemented your snippet into my code and it works properly when I set a timeout to simulate a long calculation, but when I remove the artificial timeout and just run the calculation it never rejects. First I thought the calc may just be too quick, but I made the program calculate `k!` through 5000 iterations (took about 1 minute total) and even with an available time of 0.0000001ms it still resolves and never rejects. Do I have to make the calc function asynchronous or something for this to work?

Comment: @DaDo JavaScript runs in a single thread. If you’re calling a long calculation directly, it will still block the thread. To prevent blocking, you can run the calculation on a server, or in a separate thread using a Web Worker. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Scenarios/Intensive_JavaScript

Comment: @DaDo Here's a nice example of [how to set up a web worker](https://www.sitepoint.com/avoiding-dom-blocking/).